# Problem with comparing two characters, one of which I get from a string with an indirect addressing

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

So I am a newbie at assembly and I need some help with some memory addresses. (I think they are memory addresses but I am not sure) So, I have a string and I want to find where does the character % occurs.

So, I made a loop, and moved the value 37 into a register(37 is the ascii value of %) and first I tried to compare that register with mystring(%counter), where counter is the register that I used as an index, incrementing it by 1 every time at the end of the loop. Then, I ran the debugging tool and saw that the compare is always false. So, I moved the value mystring(%counter) into another register, and when I ran the gdb again I saw that there was a very big number there. So, I thought that was a memory address or something and tried to load mystring(%counter) into a register. Neither did this work.

```
.text

mystring:  .asciz  "asdb%asd%af "  //that's how I declared my string


loop1:

     cmpq %r9 , %r14  //in r9 I have the length of the string, r14 is the 
                      //index

     jl if1



if1: 


     movw $37 , %bx

     leaw mystring(%r14)  , %ax
     cmpw %ax , %bx
     je something
     incq %r14
     jmp loop1
```

So that jump if equal never happens even if mystring(%r14) points to a % , and when I ran the debugger, it showed a big number in ax. (I also tried to resize the registers, as I hoped that would change the values somehow, that's why I used the w suffix.)
P.S This is my first post here so don't be too harsh if I did not respect some rules or something. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with this code.

1. The string consists of 8-bit ASCII characters, so the code should use an 8-bit comparison.
2. It doesn't ever read the value of the character from the string.
3. It never exits the loop if the '%' character isn't found.

Here's your code with those problems fixed.

```
.text

mystring:  .asciz  "asdb%asd%af "  //that's how I declared my string



loop1:
     cmpq %r9, %r14   //in r9 I have the length of the string, r14 is the 
                      //index
     jge endloop1

     movb $37, %bl
     movb mystring(%r14), %al
     cmpb %bl, %al
     je something
     incq %r14
     jmp loop1

endloop1:
```

---

I have a few additional suggestions to improve this code:

1. Put the loop check at the end of the loop.
2. Replace the `movb` and `cmpb` instructions with a single instruction.

   ```
        cmpq %r9, %r14    // This check may not be necessary if the string
        jge skiploop1     // length is known to be greater than 0.

    loop1:
        cmpb $37, mystring(%r14)
        je something
        incq %r14
        cmpq %r9, %r14   // r9 is the length of the string, r14 is the 
                         // index
        jl loop1

    skiploop1:
   ```